# Azure DevOps AzureBlob File Copy Task Wildcard Directory Source Path

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have a Release Pipeline setup to extract my build artifact and then I use the RegEx Find & Replace task to update a few configuration files on my static website before uploading via AzureBlob File Copy task.

What I have currently works. However I have to use the full source path to the "wwwroot" folder in order to for the correct files to be uploaded.

My concern is that my builds may change the directory structure that gets dropped as a build artifact which will break my release tasks.

I've tried to use various wildcards for the source path such as:

```
**/wwwroot/*
*/*wwwroot/*
```

And many other variations to no avail.

I read in some of the docs that wildcards won't work for directory paths in this task but  was hoping there was a way to work around this as I have long term concerns about the path changing over time. I looked at a few other tasks in the marketplace but nothing seems to fit the bill and I couldn't find any definitive guidance on the matter. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/wwwroot/*.*`(or *.json,*.xml...) in `Source` input.

(If the `wwwroot` folder doesn't have subfolders and all files within that folder can match format `*.*`)

2.Otherwise I suggest you archive the wwwroot folder first before uploading it:

[image]

[image]

Use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` to get working directory and then use full path(not recommend using `*` here) to archive the specific `wwwroot` folder. Then upload the zipped folder which contains all content of your `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: wwwroot has many subfolders and they may change over time. I'm not sure I understand the point of archiving the files? I need them to copy over as is. In fact the previous step before this is to extract them from the source build artifact. Perhaps you are suggesting I archive them after performing the regex tasks and then extracting them AGAIN to a directory closer to the root that I can have greater control over so as not to have to rely on the "/d_C/a/1/s/AdminPortal/obj/Release/netstandard2.1/PubTmp/Out/wwwroot/*" source? That is my main concern is that this path could vary over time...

Comment: @INNVTV In my test, the Azure File Copy task will only copy files in current folder `wwwroot` folder, it won't copy the sub-folders of `wwwroot` folder. So I suggest you can archive the wwwroot folder if it contains subfolders. The `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/wwwroot/` can always represent the wwwroot folder under working directory, have you tried that?

Comment: I'll try that. Will report back. Thank you!

Comment: @INNVTV Feel free to let me know if there's any update :)